# Warning: Undefined array key ""

Tags: php, mysql

Estuve realizando que segun un texto la fila de mi tabla tendrá un color determinado. El código funciona pero me manda un error como este:

> Warning: Undefined array key "" in
> C:\xampp\htdocs\notificaciones\vertareas.php on line 113

Si es posible que alguien pueda ayudarme ya que no puedo encontrar el error. Adjunto mi código también:

```
<?php
$consulta = "SELECT * FROM mensaje";
$ejecutarConsulta = mysqli_query($mysqli, $consulta);
$verFilas = mysqli_num_rows($ejecutarConsulta);
$fila = mysqli_fetch_array($ejecutarConsulta);

if (!$ejecutarConsulta) {
    echo"Error en la consulta";
} else {
    if ($verFilas < 1) {
        echo"<tr><td>Sin registros</td></tr>";
    } else {
        for($i=0; $i<=$fila; $i++){
            {
                $fila6_color = array(
                    'En desarrollo' => '#ECF705',
                    'Finalizada' => '#15D50F',
                    'No Realizada' => '#EF0E0E'
                );
            }
// la LINEA 113 es la siguiente
            echo "<tr bgcolor='".$fila6_color[$fila[6]]."'>
                <td>$fila[0]</td>
                <td>$fila[1]</td>
                <td>$fila[2]</td>
                <td>$fila[3]</td>
                <td>$fila[4]</td>
                <td>$fila[5]</td>
                <td>$fila[6]</td>
                <td>$fila[7]</td>
                <td>$fila[8]</td>
            </tr>";
            $fila = mysqli_fetch_array($ejecutarConsulta);
        }
    }
}
?>              
    </table>
</div>
```

Comment: Imagino que las llaves que sobra después del `for` son un error al copiar el código. Con respecto al error, seguramente se debe a que `$fila[6]` es igual a `''` (_vacío_) y como en el arreglo `$fila6_color` no esta contemplado este caso, da error.

Comment: Tu código no tiene sentido. No estás recorriendo bien las filas, pues haces dos veces lo de `$fila = mysqli_fetch_array($ejecutarConsulta);`  sin sentido en ambas, pues luego pretendes que esto funcione: `$i<=$fila`  cuando $fila representa un conjunto de valores de fila de la tabla `mensaje` y en ningún caso parece un número. Léete como se recorren los resultados de las consultas mysqli [en los ejemplos de la documentación](https://www.php.net/manual/es/mysqli-result.fetch-array.php) para hacerlo bien, y luego reformula la pregunta con los nuevos errores que tengas, pues ahora hay demasiados

Comment: Además de lo que comenta @masterguru, te recomendaría utilizar `mysqli_fetch_array($ejecutarConsulta,MYSQLI_ASSOC);` por varios motivos: queda más legible utilizando nombres de columna, queda preparado por si cambia la estructura de la tabla, etc. Y el recorrido ha de ser con `while ($fila=mysqli_fetch_array($ejecutarConsulta,MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {` en lugar de ese for y los `mysqli_fetch_array` repetidos

Comment: Sobre el error de la 113... en realidad es porque el valor de `$fila[6]` no coincide con ninguno de los índices de tu array. Haz un `echo $fila[6]` para ver qué valor tiene, y me imagino que verás que no es ninguno de ellos

Answer (score 0, accepted):

asegurate que $fila en la posicion 6 tenga algo, mas alla de eso deberias usar comillas para poder mostrar los valores del array.
bassandome en tu codigo haria algo asi donde valido que exista la posicion 6 del array fila y despues valido que exista la posicion de fila6_color que buscas, si la tenes agrega el background, sino no.

```
echo "<tr ".(isset( $fila[6] ) && isset( $fila6_color[$fila[6]] ) ? 'bgcolor="'.$fila6_color[$fila[6]].'"' : '').">
     <td>".$fila[0]."</td>
     <td>".$fila[1]."</td>
     <td>".$fila[2]."</td>
     <td>".$fila[3]."</td>
     <td>".$fila[4]."</td>
     <td>".$fila[5]."</td>
     <td>".$fila[6]."</td>
     <td>".$fila[7]."</td>
     <td>".$fila[8]."</td>
   </tr>";
```

saludos